# How To Get An Output From Shapes Overlapping? Python 3.5 Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game similar to Block Dodger in python using tkinter.
What I want to do is make an output from when a rectangle touches another rectangle. I found an answer similar to my question, but it did not explain what to do and how to use the command. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def change_coord(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(a, 20,0)
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(a, -20,0)

def tet1():
    canvas.move(b, 0, 30)
    root.after(250, tet1)

def tet2():
    canvas.move(c, 0, 20)
    root.after(250, tet2)

def tet3():
    canvas.move(d, 0, 50)
    root.after(250, tet3)


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=5000, bg='white')
canvas.pack(pady=0)

a = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='red')
b = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='blue')
c = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='blue')
d = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='blue')


canvas.move(a, 450, 850)
canvas.move(c, 450, 0)
canvas.move(d, 675, 0)

canvas.bind("<Motion>", change_coord)
root.bind_all('<Left>', change_coord)
root.bind_all('<Right>', change_coord)

tet1()
root.after(200, tet2)
root.after(2000, tet3)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure how I can do this, so I'd appreciate some help with it. Thanks :)
-Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if `a` overlaps any object you can get `a` coords and use with `find_overlapping()`. It gives you list with objects which overlap `a`

```
def check_collision():

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(a)

    result = canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    if b in result:
        print('b overlaps a')
    if c in result:
        print('c overlaps a')
    if d in result:
        print('d overlaps a')

    root.after(250, check_collision)
```

You can run it with `after()`

Or you can use `find_overlapping` for every object separately - and then you can stop object and remove from canvas.

```
def tet1():
    canvas.move(b, 0, 30)

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(b)

    result = canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    if a in result:
        print('b overlaps a')
        canvas.delete(b)
    else:
        root.after(250, tet1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me! :)